# How can I get a table to print under a picture using a loop in a .rmd with word_document?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, cpu-word, kable, flextable

I am trying to create a .rmd file that takes all of the pictures for a field day and the notes that was taken and create a report. I am able to get the pictures to plot but the no matter what I try the table with the notes does not want to print. Below is the loop I am utilizing:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(subset_Inventory_data)) {
  
singlept <- subset_Inventory_data[i,]

picture <- pictureLookup[singlept$GlobalID == pictureLookup$REL_GLOBAL,]

#PRINT PICTURE
plot(image_read(paste(baseURL,picture$UID,sep = "")) %>%
  # image_resize("400x400") %>%
  image_rotate(degrees = 90)
)

#creating table underneath picture
Categories <- c("Latitude", "Longitude", "Road Width", "Conditon", "Lock Present","Additional Notes")

sum_table <- data.frame(Category = character(),
                        Information = character(),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sum_table <- rbind(sum_table,Categories,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(sum_table) <- Categories

sum_table$Latitude <- sprintf("%f",singlept$LAT)
sum_table$Longitude <-sprintf("%f",singlept$LONG)
sum_table$`Road Width` <- paste(singlept$Gate_Width,"feet")
sum_table$Conditon <- singlept$Condition
sum_table$`Lock Present` <- singlept$GlobalID
sum_table$`Additional Notes` <- singlept$General_Notes

#TRIED FLEXTABLE
ft <- flextable(sum_table)
ft <- fontsize(ft, size = 12)
ft <- autofit(ft)
print(ft)
#TRIED KABLE
print(kable(sum_table,"latex"))
}
```

Comment: You can use function docx_value, see https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/docx_value.html